# Eclipse: Already sure a function is working properly, want to skip going over it when debugging

Tags: c, eclipse

I have some functions that are working properly. But whenever I debug and call one of them I must go inside it all over again. I could press F6 for that whenever I call one but for that I have to stay on guard for that the entire debug. It'd be awesome to add them to some kind of list of working functions which I then skip when debugging. Does this kind of list exist?

Comment: Why not set breakpoints?

Comment: Based on what I know about how single-stepping is implemented, I think it would be very slow. Basically the debugger would still need to single-step, then for each instruction reverse-map it back to which function it is part of, and look that up in the list. Do as @user694733 says and use breakpoints to corral the code of interest.

Comment: Depending on the debugger used, there are sometimes *conditional* breakpoints available..

Comment: To expand on the answer from @user694733, set a breakpoint at the first line of the function that you wish to skip. when you get to the first line, press F7 (Step Return)